# npm - Don't Want To List Package On devDependencies Inside package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies

When I try to install npm package using command `npm i -d <package-name>`, it always listing the package inside `dependencies` instead of `devDependencies`. It works before, but I suddenly get this problem without knowing what is causing it.

I have tried to reset `NODE_ENV` (I am not sure if this is related since I use windows), deleting `package.lock.json`, uninstall **VSCode**'s extensions, cleaning `npm cache` reinstall the `node_modules` and even reinstall **NODEJs**, but the problem still persist.

Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: If you want to save package to `devDependencies` you must use `-D` instead of `-d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NPM Docs referring to this](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#shorthands-and-other-cli-niceties)

Use `-D` (mind the uppercase) to save as a devDependency, as `-d` is the same as `--loglevel info`